# Strange notebook response

Tags: testing, jupyter-notebook, training-data, mode, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to run the next code on data samples 10000 image with size 224*224*3 jupyter notebook but I get this error
"The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." I tried the code before on dataset contains 50000 image and size 32*32*3 and was working well.

```
def train(g_model, d_model, gan_model, dataset, latent_dim, n_epochs=100, n_batch=128):
    bat_per_epo = int(dataset.shape[0] / n_batch)
    half_batch = int(n_batch / 2)  #the discriminator model is updated for a half batch of real samples 
                            #and a half batch of fake samples, combined a single batch. 
    # manually enumerate epochs and bacthes. 
    for i in range(n_epochs):
        # enumerate batches over the training set
        for j in range(bat_per_epo):


            X_real, y_real = generate_real_samples(dataset, half_batch)
            d_loss_real, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X_real, y_real) 
            # generate 'fake' examples
            X_fake, y_fake = generate_fake_samples(g_model, latent_dim, half_batch)
            # update discriminator model weights
            d_loss_fake, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X_fake, y_fake)
            #d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_real, d_loss_fake) #Average loss if you want to report single..
            # prepare points in latent space as input for the generator
            X_gan = generate_latent_points(latent_dim, n_batch)
            g_loss = gan_model.train_on_batch(X_gan, y_gan)

            # Print losses on this batch
            print('Epoch>%d, Batch %d/%d, d1=%.3f, d2=%.3f g=%.3f' %
                (i+1, j+1, bat_per_epo, d_loss_real, d_loss_fake, g_loss))
# save the generator model
    g_model.save('GAN_model.h5')


latent_dim = 100
`discriminator = define_discriminator()`
`generator = define_generator(latent_dim)`
`gan_model = define_gan(generator, discriminator)`
`dataset = load_real_samples()
`train(generator, discriminator`, gan_model, dataset, latent_dim, n_epochs=2)`
```